# Rules for Gmail for setting specific folders for emails received

Tags: gmail

Microsoft Outlook automatically groups items by date. And can also group items manually by using standard arrangements or by creating own custom grouping and the best one is **creating rules**. I got rules with my outlook before, this setting **specific folder for specific emails that I received**. This stuff I'am looking for my gmail. Is this **possible with gmail** or there are **existing way** for gmail to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of what you can accomplish in Outlook rules you can do with Gmail filters. Gmail filters let you use a search term and, when a message arrives, if it matches the search, it will apply the actions of the filter. There are several things you can do, but primarily what you're interested in is applying a label.

Please note that labels in Gmail are different than folders in Outlook. A message/conversation can have multiple different labels, whereas in Outlook (and similar mail clients) a message can only be in one folder.

There's no "grouping" or custom sorting. All conversations are listed in strict reverse chronological order. To limit your view, you need to search. (Which is what you would expect from Google.) In fact, viewing all of the messages with a particular label is just a search with a special operator: `label:{label-name}`.

More information:

- Gmail Support:

  - [Organize your Gmail inbox using labels](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/118708)
  - [Create rules to filter your emails](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579)
- How-To Geek: [Inbox Management and Labels](https://www.howtogeek.com/school/gmail-guide/lesson3/)